# How to make the value of another column in a table to be the value of the primary key column in the same table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySql Db_table called Branch with two fields i.e "id" and "name". id is the primary key in this table. I want the value of the "name" column to be the value passed onto the "id"  column. For example, I need something like this: if name == "cmc" then id should be equal to "cmc" etc.

```
 id  | name

 CMC | CMC
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update with the following logic:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET id = name
WHERE name = 'cmc';
```

If instead you want the `name` column to always reflect the value of the `id`, you may make `name` a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable AS (
    id varchar(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(100) AS (id),
    ...
)
```

Comment: But do i have to first create the table then later update it with this query? Isn't there a query that I can use while creating the table putting this relationship on the fly such that if I enter the name value it automatically reflects as the value of the id?

Comment: Am getting an error "An opening bracket was expected (near 'AS') ,how can I can refactor this query?

Comment: Typo...the expression for the computed column needs to be in parentheses.

Comment: And the 'AS' keyword after the table_name is not required

Answer (score 0):

Use AFTER INSERT trigger.

Something like this

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER after_your_table_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON your_table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.name = 'CMC' THEN
    UPDATE your_table
    SET id = NEW.name;
  END IF;
END$$
```

Unfortunately I don't have MySql installed on my system to check exactly this code works, but you can check some examples [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-insert-trigger/).

Comment: I mean assume the data is not yet in the table, so how can I update your query above? I have tried it this way but it's throwing an error:
CREATE TRIGGER id_insert
    AFTER INSERT
    ON branch FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN     
        SET id = NEW.name;
      END IF;
    END$$